# Why am i not able to initialize the linkedlist?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, singly-linked-list

I was trying to make a single linkedlist but the head pointer keeps pointing at null hence there is not output after taking the size and the elements of the linkedlist. Also when i take the head as an pointer inside of Main function it gives me segmentation fault when i try to call push and display function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
}node;


void push(node *head,int value){
    node * newnode= (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    printf("%d",value);
    if(head==NULL){
        head = newnode;
        return;

    }
    node* iter = head;
    while(iter->next!=NULL){
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    iter->next = newnode;
}

void display(node *head){
    node *iter = head;
    while(iter!=NULL){
        printf("%d->",iter->data);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    node *head = NULL;
    int size;
    scanf("%d",&size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        int value;
        scanf("%d",&value);
        push(head,value);
    }
    display(head);
}
```

Comment: `void push(node *head, int value)` should be `void push(node **head, int value)`.  You should call it like `push(&head,value);` and access it, in `push`, with `if(*head==NULL)`, etc.

Comment: @FiddlingBits can you explain a little bit why is this happening I mean in the previous method the pointer should have pointed toward the newnode but instead of that it kept pointing towards null. Isn't the both ways same as we are accessing the address at which the pointer is pointing using dereferencing so it means the same.  NVM I got it thanks man

Comment: The `main` passes a *copy* of `head` to the function, i.e. its value. Another way is to use the function's `return` value, such as `node *push(node *head,int value)` with `return head;` and call it with `head = push(head,value);`

Comment: Implementation of a singly linked list in C - https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/terms/6680/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `push` deals with a copy of the value of the pointer `head` defined in main. Changing the copy within the function leaves the original pointer unchanged. That is the function parameter `head` that is a local variable of the function is initialized by the value of the pointer head defined in main and used as an argument expression.

You need to pass the original pointer to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer  to it.  Thus dereferencing the pointer you can get a direct access to the original object.

The function can look the following way

```
int push( node **head, int value )
{
    node *newnode = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = newnode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newnode->data = value;
        newnode->next = NULL;

        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = newnode;
    } 

    return success;
}
```

And the function is called like

```
push( &head, value );
```

Within the function you should check whether memory for the new node was allocated successfully. Otherwise the function can invoke undefined behavior.

As for the function `display` then its parameter should be declared with qualifier `const` because the function does not change nodes of the list

```
void display( const node *head){
```

Pay also attention to that it is inefficient to add new nodes to the end of the singly-linked list. It would be better to define a two-sided singly-linked list that contains two pointers to the begining of the list and its last node.

That can be achieved by defining one more structure as for example

```
typedef struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
} list;
```

In this case the function `push` can look the following way

```
int push( list *lst, int value )
{
    node *newnode = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = newnode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newnode->data = value;
        newnode->next = NULL;

        if ( lst->head == NULL )
        {
            lst->head = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            lst->tail->next = newnode;
        }

        lst->tail = newnode;   
    } 

    return success;
}
```

and the functoin is called in main like

```
int main( void )
{
    list lst = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
    
    push( &lst, 10 );

    // or

    if ( !push( &lst, 10 ) ) puts( "Error: not enough memory." );    

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `head` you pass in your `push()` function is a `node*`, which is passed by value (the pointer itself is passed by value, the `node` pointed to is passed by reference/address) to the function `push()`. This means that you can modify the `node` `head` is pointing to, but you can't make `head` point to something else (to be correct, you can, but this changes only lasts during that function call and does not effect the original `head` from `main()`.

Therefore you need to pass a pointer to a `node*`. Your function would then look like this:

```
void push(node** head, int value) {
    node* newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    printf("%d", value);
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = newnode;
        return;

    }
    node* iter = *head;
    while (iter->next != NULL) {
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    iter->next = newnode;
}
```

and you would call it like `push(&head, value);`.

Answer (score 0):

In the program you either have to return the head or declare it globally. Here is a solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}   node;

node *push(node *head, int value){
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    printf("In the Push method : %d\n", value);
    if(head == NULL){
        head = newnode;
        return head;
    }
    node *iter = head;
    while(iter->next != NULL){
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    iter->next = newnode;
    return head;
}

void display(node *head){
    node *iter = head;
    while(iter != NULL){
        printf("%d->", iter->data);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    node *head = NULL;
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size of the linked list : ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int value;
        printf("Enter the value : ");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        head = push(head, value);
    }
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your "declare it globally" is not a good solution and this answer overlooks another solution, using argument `node **head` as detailed elsewhere. Otherwise it seems fine.

Comment: Yeah, I also don't like the practice of declating variables globally and I support you suggestion of declareing the function with `node **head` as return type.

Comment: That is not the return type, which is still `void`. It is the argument type.